# CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll Direct download?

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

I started using a 3rd party API that depends on XML-RPC.NET `using CookComputing.XmlRpc;` I can download the source files but there is not an actual "XmlRpcV2.dll" file anywhere in the zip.

It looks like you are supposed to build it, but when I open the src project in MS Visual C# EXPRESS and do the conversion wizard, then try to build it I am getting 842 build errors about not being able to find types or namespaces for the following: NUnit, TestFixture, TextFixtureAttribute, Test, etc ...

Does anyone know where I can download the "XmlRpcV2.dll" file so that I can simply drop it into my C# project and start using it? I can't seem to find a direct download of the compiled dll anywhere online. Is it perhaps used in other downloadable projects somewhere?

I downloaded version 2.5.0

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What was the 3rd party API that depends on XMLPRC?

Comment: I've used a handful of APIs since but in that particular case I believe it was InfusionSoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the bin directory in the download - you should see CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll. This is what you want. 
I assume you obtained the download from here: http://www.xml-rpc.net/download.html

Comment: The thing that threw me off was they named it "CookComputing.XmlRpcV2.dll" instead of putting it in the "CookComputing" folder and naming it "XmlRpcV2.dll"

Comment: For those who cannot see the file: have a look at Charles Cooks answer below. Thanks Microsoft :(

Answer (score 14):

This is a problem if you're using Windows Explorer to unzip the distribution file (Explorer hides the dlls). The zip file structure will be changed in version 3.0 onwards to avoid prevent this from happening.

Perhaps the best way these days to add XML-RPC.NET to a project is to use NuGet.

Comment: Yep, the same problem just got me - unzipping with 7Zip instead of Windows Explorer worked fine and now I can see the .dll and more.

Comment: For NuGet, enter "xml-rpc.net" as search term, since there are many other XML RPC libraries.